# Скрыть footer на главной странице

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Как скрыть футер только на одной странице (главной)?

Comment: `if(is_home()){код футера}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!is_front_page()) {
    get_footer();
}
```

Вместо функции `is_front_page()` можно использовать `is_home()`, она работает быстрее, но в случае, если для главной установлена статическая страница, не подойдёт

Кроме того, можно просто не вызывать функцию `get_footer()` (она отвечает подключение файла `footer.php` на страницу) в файле `front-page.php`, который используется для оформления главной страницы в сайтах на вордпресс

Comment: спасибо за ответ! Только начинаю осваивать сайтостроение. Эту функцию, ничего не изменяя просто добавить в footer.php?

Comment: нет, если вы хотите управлять выводом кода прямо в `footer.php`, то блок с условием `if (!is_front_page())` должен обрамлять весь код подвала: `if (!is_front_page()) { тут весь уже созданный код футера }`

Comment: Спасибо! знаний на вопрос хватило, а знаний на ответ нехватает. Правильнее, я так понял, просто не вызывать функцию get_footer() на главной странице. но я на Вордпресс привинтил тему BeFree от Maffin. У них в сборке не нашел файла front-page.php. Поэтому выход один получается нужно вставить if (!is_front_page()) перед <?php endif; ?>

Comment: С готовыми темами нужно осторожнее. Если дадите ссылку на архив с темой, могу помочь разобраться что к чему

Comment: ссылку прилагаю https://cloud.mail.ru/public/FeUj/vS1KiK1tv Буду признателен, если будет время, спасибо! У меня пока не получается. Попробовал в page.php и в footer.php добавить if (!is_front_page()) {}, пока не получается (возможно правда делаю ошибки при вставке)

Comment: У вас в теме не используется отдельный файл для главной страницы, поэтому необходимо внести правки в `index.php`, находящийся в папке с темой (`\wp-content\themes\betheme`). Находите строку (если ничего не редактировали, то строка номер 195) `<?php get_footer(); ?>` и меняете её на `<?php if (!is_front_page()) {get_footer();} ?>`. Всё, после этого подвал будет выводиться на всех страницах, кроме главной :)

Comment: Видимо хитрая тема попалась)) Ни в какую не хочет пропадать подвал нигде)) http://xn----itbalcldc6agyegbk5lg.xn--p1ai/

Comment: Это странно, потому что у меня всё получилось. Тогда попробуйте решение совсем в лоб. В файле `footer.php` найдите открывающий тэг `<footer id="Footer" class="clearfix">`. Прямо перед ним вставляете `<?php if (!is_front_page()) { ?>` и сразу после закрывающего тэга `</footer>` закрываем блок `<?php } ?>`. http://screencast.com/t/FJcbVXij

Comment: alenkins Вам огромное спасибо за помощь! Все получилось! Если могу чем то помочь, обращайтесь